# MySQL password encrypt validation

Tags: mysql, encode

```
insert into test(username,pwd) values('Jim',ENCODE('123456','Jim'));
select username from test where username='Jim' and pwd=ENCODE('123456','Jim')

insert into test(username,pwd) values('Ryan',SHA('123456'))
select username from test where username='Ryan' and pwd=SHA('123456')

insert into test(username,pwd) values('Jack',MD5('123456'))
select username from test where username='Jack' and pwd=MD5('123456')
```

Why I can't get a right result by using `SHA` and `MD5`? Passwords are both 123456, but with different encryption methods I cannot get a right result.

The first can output "Jim" correctly. But the second and the third one cannot output "Ryan" or "Jack", the result set is `null`. Why? I want know how to validate a user by encrypted password.

Comment: what field type and length is "pwd"?  MD5 and SHA are not encryption but rather a hash - the difference is you can reverse encryption but a hash is one way only. This isn't a problem with your example but I thought I should point it out.

Comment: Also, the tags "java" and "web" are not relevant to the question

Comment: pwd field is varchar(20)..

Comment: SHA produces a 64 character string (`CHAR(64)`). MD5 produces a 32 character string (`CHAR(32)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you are doing something wrong ? Works fine for me.

[SQL Fiddle link with the queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00700/3).

My hunch is that you are storing truncated versions of the hash.

Comment: That seems like the only way this could fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your field types as your 20-character `VARCHAR` field is truncating the hashes:

`MD5` produces a 32-character string so use `CHAR(32)`.

`SHA` produces a 64-character string so use `CHAR(64)`.

You should always use `CHAR` over `VARCHAR` when you know the length of input, for performance reasons (SQL knows how much to allocate).

Answer (score 0):

**Note
Exploits for the MD5 and SHA-1 algorithms have become known. You may wish to consider using one of the other encryption functions described in this section instead, such as SHA2().**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html